# Getting the value of a parent computed function, from a child component in VueJS

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component

I'm trying to pass the value of a computed method which changes, into my child component, with little success.  I'm making a button component which has several different save states - yet my button is always stuck on one and doesn't update with the parent.

My computed method works fine when I'm not trying to use this button as a component and just put it directly into the parent, so the issue is how I'm passing the data.

Parent

```
  computed: {
    isSaving() {
      return (
  this.$_.values(this.$store.getters["CommonSettings/saving"]).filter(
          status => status && status != "done"
        ).length > 0
      );
    }


 <SaveButton v-bind:saveState="isSaving"/>
```

Child

```
<script>    
export default {
  name: "saveButton",
  props: ['saveState']
}
</script>
<template>
  <div class="settings--button-wrapper">
    <button v-if="!saveState">
      Save
    </button>
    <button v-if="saveState">
      Saving..
    </button>
  </div>
</template>
```

Am I doing anything which is obviously wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

Parent

```
computed: {
    isSaving() {
      // add `this.`
      return (
          this.status && this.status != "done"
        )
      );
    }
}

<SaveButton v-bind:saveState="isSaving"/>
```

Child

```
<script>    
export default {
  name: "saveButton",
  props: ['saveState']
}
</script>
<template>
  <div class="settings--button-wrapper">
    <!-- use `saveState` -->
    <button>
      {{ saveState ? 'Saving..' : 'Save' }}
    </button>
  </div>
</template>
```

Comment: Sorry - as I stated before, the computed method works fine when this button isn't a component (use it in the same template).  It's only breaking when I have split this button into a separate component - so this doesn't fix it.  

I think the issue is my component is rendering with the initial state - and then it doesn't get any updates after that.

Comment: @s89_  `<button> {{ saveState ? 'Saving..' : 'Save' }} </button>`  Does this work correctly?

Comment: Unfortunately no.  Like I said - my button works fine when it's not a component.  The data isn't being passed correctly and updated when the save state in the parent changes.

Comment: @s89_ This is correct answer. `I think the issue is my component is rendering with the initial state - and then it doesn't get any updates after that.` - exactly! Because `isSaving` in the child is assigned with the value of `saveState` prop when child component is created (one single time). Changes of the `saveState` prop in the future (from parent) have no effect on child's data. That's why you should use `saveState` prop directly

Comment: @MichalLevý - yep - this is what I tried initially.  I tried it again and that still doesn't work, so I'm missing something here still.  Using saveState directly doesn't update in the child.

Comment: @MichalLevý - the saveState comes from a computed property in the parent.  Should I make it come from a data value instead?

Comment: @s89_ Update your question with the code where you declare and update your `status` variable in the parent

Answer (score -1):

You should use `saveState` instead of isSaving.

Comment: Thanks but I tried that first and it didn't resolve my issue.